# Access 2007: Unrecognized database format

Tags: sharepoint, ms-access-2007

My client has an Access 2007 (accdb) file. It's stored on SharePoint, and there are three users that check it out, make updates, and check it back in. One user is on Windows 7, another on Vista, the third on either Vista or XP (my client wasn't sure).

There are no linked tables, and it's only ever used by one user at a time.

I'm told the user on 7 spent several hours adding data, then published to SharePoint. Now, any use that attempts to read the data gets hit with the "Unrecognized database format" error. They sent me a copy, and I get the same thing. It's one particular table (the most important, of course) that does this when trying to open; all the other objects (queries, forms, etc.) open fine, except for those that rely on the table.

Attempting to compact and repair gives the error "The Microsoft Office Access database engine could not find the object 'tbl_TableName'. Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly." I also tried to import into a new `accdb` file, and got the same "Unrecognized database format error."

I suspect it's completely corrupted, but my client is frantic. If there are no fixes for this, what about these Access recovery programs I saw while Googling this? Do they work? Have a recommendation?

Comment: What do you mean "completely corrupted"? That seems to be contradicted by your statement taht the queries/forms are accessible. Secondly, you're not following best practices. Data tables should be stored in a single ACCDB and front-end objects (forms/reports/queries/etc.) in a separate ACCDB linked to it. Yes, this makes things more complex in a Sharepoint scenario, but you've discovered one of the problems of the monolithic model -- corruption in one part can hose the other part. Try importing the tables into a newly-created ACCDB. Maybe only one or a few of the tables are corrupted.

Comment: I meant the table is completely corrupted. I guess I didn't make that clear. Also, I agree about best practices, but this isn't my baby. Finally, my question does state I attempted to import without success.

Comment: Can the user on 7 still open the table?  And do they still have their copy of the database?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried importing into mdb format instead?  maybe going down a version will kick it loose.